# Large (10ft.) Creature Crossing 5ft. Gap

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

So, basically, the party is going to be in a sewer and there's going to be a large (10ft. square) creature on the other side of a 5 ft. sewage channel.  The party probably won't be eager to cross the channel and I could just have the creature start on the same side as the party through some other means, but I'd like the creature to cross the channel for more flavor and to introduce some possibility of things not going the creature's way.

I could just make my own acrobatics DC or something, but is there a more rules-oriented way of doing this?  Is it a guaranteed success for the creatures stride, he just has to use a whole move action or something?  There may not be rules for this, which would surprise me, but if such is the case how would you guys work this out?

If it's helpful at all, the creature is an ogre.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange site. If you haven't already, would you mind looking at [this tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) of how our site works? Also, I am not sure if your creature is trying to jump over a gap or squeeze through a narrow tunnel or what. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look at that!

And in my head, the creature would attempt to just "step over" a gap in the floor to get to the other side of the gap, as opposed to maneuvering through a tunnel or something.  If nothing else, I could just have the creature jump over the gap; that suffices to solve the dilemma with the answer given by KRyan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A long jump is an Acrobatics check with a DC equal to the distance jumped (doubled without a running start). So the ogre could jump the channel with a DC 5 check if it got a running start, or DC 10 if it did not. Both of these checks should be pretty easy.

Either way, the jump is just a part of the ogre’s movement, not a separate action. So the ogre can jump the channel as the first 5 feet of its movement and continue on to the PCs.

Comment: Suppose you have a colossal creature, for which stepping over a 5 foot ditch should not be a problem at all. Is there any other solution in that case, or must that creature also make a trivial jump check?

Comment: They will only fall if they can fit into the ditch. Otherwise you follow the "invalid space" rules, you cant get into what you don't fit. A colossal dragon will never be able to enter a 20 ft square room.

Comment: @ShadowKras Hilariously, the Colossal dragon *can* fit into a 20-ft.×20-ft. (and, let's hope, also *×20-ft.*) room—see Squeezing in [Terrain and Obstacles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Terrain-and-Obstacles)—but only by taking 1 min. to cram in and , afterward, who *else* can fit in that room? I dunno. The Colossal dragon that fails the Jump check to cross the 5-ft. gap should end up at the last legal square it occupied—a dragon pothole (*for* not *made of*), if you will.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like these Pathfinder provides DMs with two types of [Hampered Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Hampered-Movement): Difficult Terrain and Obstacles. Both take double the standard moment to cross, while obstacles can require skill checks.

While any creature can jump over small gaps, if a creature is bigger than said gap, it could reasonably be implied that it could just walk over said gap. I would argue that if said gap is small enough to fit the creature while squeezed, it is an obstacle and should require a skill check. While, if the gap is smaller than this you could simply treat it as difficult terrain.

For your specific example. While the Ogre is Large and takes up a ten foot square area on the map, in reality the actual ogre only occupies a tiny portion of that 10'x10' area and can fit into a 5' wide gap when squeezed. So a skill check should be used. What happens if a creature fails their jump or obstacle skill check, does not appear to be spelled out by the rules. I do not see any text stating the minimum size of gap a creature can fall into.

> Difficult terrain, obstacles, and poor visibility can hamper movement (see Table: Hampered Movement for details). When movement is hampered, each square moved into usually counts as two squares, effectively reducing the distance that a character can cover in a move.
>
> If more than one hampering condition applies, multiply all additional costs that apply. This is a specific exception to the normal rule for doubling.
>
> In some situations, your movement may be so hampered that you don't have sufficient speed even to move 5 feet (1 square). In such a case, you may use a full-round action to move 5 feet (1 square) in any direction, even diagonally. Even though this looks like a 5-foot step, it's not, and thus it provokes attacks of opportunity normally. (You can't take advantage of this rule to move through impassable terrain or to move when all movement is prohibited to you.)
>
> You can't run or charge through any square that would hamper your movement.